# Conjugaison éblouir

Tags: conjugaison

Ce matin à la radio j'ai entendu la phrase :

> la nuit les phares des voitures /meblui/
>   
>  — *m’ébloui(en)t ?*

moi j'aurais plutôt dit :

> la nuit les phares des voitures m’éblouissent.

Laquelle de ces phrases est juste ?

Comment: @LukeSawczak La forme « éblouient » n'existe pas ( https://conjugaison.lemonde.fr/conjugaison/search?verb=%C3%A9blouir ) ; on trouve seulement « éblouissent »

Comment: @LPH Bien sûr que non, c'est pourquoi il y a cette question. But it's the closest alternative theory for what the person might have had in mind.

Comment: @LukeSawczak Ah ! Je vois ! Vous supposez que la personne pourrait être d'une telle ignorance en ce qui concerne sa langue que de ne pas savoir que la seule forme est « éblouissent » ; je doute fort que cela soit le cas : les formes connexes, « éblouissons », « éblouissez », rendent cela difficile. Néanmoins, il serait bon de signifier clairement dans le texte de la question la raison pour faire figurer cette forme inexistante.

Comment: Comme tu dis que c'est une publicité, es-tu certain de la citation ou pourrait-ce être quelque chose comme : "la lumière des phares des voitures m'éblouit" ?

Comment: @LukeSawczak You're probably right about it being the closest alternative theory, but my first thought was "**La nuit**  (avec ses phares des chars) m’éblouit" (night blindness?). Regardless, IMO, the "what OP heard" part of the question should perhaps be written in "phonetic code" (all those symbols that I know nothing about, not even what they're called) either with or without all the possible spellings that would/could jive with that "code" in parentheses after the "code," including the good one you added to the question.

Comment: @PapaPoule You have a good point about phonetic spelling. (I was also thinking about the *la nuit* thing, but figured that there was no point speculating about what OP might or might not have heard.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

C'est évidemment « éblouissent » qui est correct ; le sujet est de la troisième personne du pluriel puisque c'est « les phares ». La personne qui parlait à la radio a fait une erreur, non pas qu'elle ne sache pas cette chose élémentaire, mais elle a tout simplement fourché de la langue.

Comment: C'es étrange vu que c'était dans une publicité. Merci d'avoir confirmé.

Comment: @TontonVelu: Les messages publicitaires ne sont pas une référence du français correct, ça se saurait ;)

Comment: @Toto : ça me fait toujours marrer comment toute une série de personnes peut passer à côté d'une erreur comme celle là, entre celui qui a écrit le texte, celui qui l'a lu, le monteur ..... comment personne ne s'en est rendu compte ? XD

Comment: @TontonVelu: Soit ça n'est pas relu, soit ils ont tous des difficultés avec la grammaire (même élémentaire) ... Voire les deux !

Comment: Honnêtement si c'est dans une publicité, j'aurais plutôt tendance à dire que tu as mal entendu ou mal compris. Quand bien même les pubs ne seraient pas des références du français correct, ça me paraît un peu gros.

Comment: @TontonVelu : Hé... bhein... dite commac... cette pub... 1/ tu t'en souviens et 2/ on sera une bonne demi-douzaine à s'en souvenir! Trop fort! Cibié, SEV Marshall... de mon temps... il n'y seraient pas parvenu à moins de deux victoires dans le Monte-Carlo!

Comment: @Destal C'est bien possible que j'ai mal entendu, je suis jamais retombé dessus depuis. Ca me parait assez gros comme faut pour être passé à la radio.

Answer (score 6):

Ce n'est pas forcément une langue qui a fourché mais peut-être simplement une variante de conjugaison peu académique mais qui n'entraîne aucun risque de confusion.

On peut en trouver quelques occurrences sur Internet, par exemple dans un commentaire sur cette [page](http://papillondesiles.over-blog.com/article-models-own-champagne-117082316.html) :

> Ahhh ils **m'éblouient** les yeux !! je suis fan là ! c'est trop beau !

ou [celle-là](https://www.wattpad.com/772947017-je-te-d%C3%A9livrerait-lee-know-minho-straykids-skz) :

> Tout à coup, les lampadaires s'allument et **m'éblouient** un instant avant de laisser apparaître la silhouette de Hyun-Su s'approcher de moi.

ou encore [là](https://bkstsk.skyrock.com/) :

> Je reconstitue tes traits a l'aveuglette en les caressants doucement. Tes yeux **m'éblouient**.

Elle est peut-être due à l'influence de la conjugaison de fuir (3<sup>e</sup> groupe) qui ne fait donc pas ***ils <s>fuissent</s>*** mais bien ***ils fuient***.

Comment: Ou, pour poursuivre sur ta dernière phrase tout simplement, comme on l'entend souvent chez les enfants, le rapprochement entre les formes du singulier et du pluriel de la 3e personne. C'est le genre d'erreurs fréquentes à l'oral, et même à la radio, j'en entends tous les jours. Tu as raison de montrer qu'à l'écrit on le trouve aussi. Le français est une langue difficile et très irrégulière.